# ERROR: generation expression is not immutable

Tags: postgresql, hash, hash-function, volatility, generated-columns

I'm trying to create a generated column with a hash on two columns, but I get error.
What's wrong with my hash?

```
create table dwh_stage.account_data_src(
    id int4 not null,
    status_nm text null,
    create_dttm timestamp null,
    update_dttm timestamp  null,
    hash bytea NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
       (digest(COALESCE(status_nm, '#$%^&'::text)
     || date_part('epoch'::text, COALESCE(timezone('UTC'::text, create_dttm), '1990-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))::text, 'sha256'::text))
        stored
);
```

Comment: Add the complete error message to your question as text.

Comment: The issue is the `createdttm` in  `timezone('UTC'::text, create_dttm)`. Have not figured out a way around it yet.

Comment: Please *always* disclose your version of Postgres. It's particularly relevant for this one. And you should mention that you installed the additional module pgcrypto. Do you need sha256 or is a bigint hash good enough?

Comment: The desired behavior can be achieved by using a trigger to manage the column's value on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datepart(text, timestamptz)` is only `STABLE`, because the result implicitly depends on the current `timezone` setting. (Well, AFAICT, extracting the epoch would be immutable, but other extracted parts vary with the setting, so the function cannot be marked `IMMUTABLE`.)

But `datepart(text, timestamp)` is `IMMUTABLE`.

Your expression is a mess in this regard to begin with. You mix `timestamptz` and `timestamp` in the `COALESCE` expression, which forces the conversion of the given `timestamp` constant ...

Drop the conversion of `create_dttm` to `timestamptz` and it works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dwh_stage.account_data_src (
  id int4 NOT NULL
, status_nm text NULL
, create_dttm timestamp NULL
, update_dttm timestamp  NULL
, hash bytea NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      digest(COALESCE(status_nm, '#$%^&'::text)
  ||  date_part('epoch', COALESCE(create_dttm, '1990-01-01'))::text, 'sha256'::text))
      STORED
);
```

Note: `create_dttm` instead of `timezone('UTC'::text, create_dttm)`.

That said, if a `bigint` hash is good enough (like it is in many cases), and you run **Postgres 14** or later, then consider instead:

```
, hash bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (hash_record_extended((status_nm, create_dttm),0)) STORED
```

Much simpler and faster. See:

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)

Comment: I have timestampz, and tried to fix the zone or convert to timestamp, but it would still be considered mutable:
`GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_part('month', created::timestamp))` and `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_part('month', created::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))`. I guess there is no way around a trigger in such case..

Comment: @Rafs: There is a simple way: `(date_part('month', created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))` The explanation is too much for a comment. Start a new question, then I'll elaborate. (Unless someone else beats me to it.)

Comment: That works, thank you. I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77599093/how-to-make-a-timestamp-with-time-zone-timestampz-column-usable-in-immutable-g).