# How to use a timestamp with time zone column in expression for a generated column?

Tags: postgresql, immutability, calculated-columns, generated-columns

I have `timestampz` column called `created`, and I want to create generated columns for month, day and year from it using Postgres 12+ [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html).

Since there is a timezone in `timestampz`, expressions like `date_part(create, ..)` and `EXTRACT (month from created)` fail  with the error:

> ```
> ERROR: generation expression is not immutable
> ```

I tried to convert to timestamp and fix the timezone, but both would still be considered mutable generation expressions:

1. `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_part('month', created::timestamp))`
2. `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (date_part('month', created::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))`

However, as indicated by [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) in his comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267155/3429115), this works:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ADD COLUMN created_year numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (date_part('month', created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) STORED;
```

Of course `EXTRACT(month from created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))` also works.

That leads me to the conclusion that if I want N timezones, I need N generated columns.
Why does this work and not #2 above? Does it have to do with the servers' configuration params when doing `::timestamp` datatype conversion?

Comment: "*Since there is a timezone in timestampz*" - confusingly, no. There is no timezone stored within a `timestamptz`, rather it is an absolutely timezone-independent instant.

Comment: "*Does it have to do with the servers' configuration params when doing :`:timestamp` datatype conversion?*" - yes.

Comment: "*if I want N timezones, I need N generated columns*" - yes, a single instant may be in different months in diffferent timezones.

Comment: You want the day, month and year. But in which time zone? Depending on your current time zone, a certain timestamp could belong to different days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this work and not #2 above?

Both #1 and #2 do not work because the cast from `timestamptz` to `timestamp` is not **immutable**. It depends on the current `timezone` setting. And generated columns only accept immutable expressions for obvious reasons. To note: [`timezone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) is not a "server setting", it's a setting for each individual session. The default is typically set in `postgresql.conf`, but clients can (and regularly will) set it as needed.

On the other hand, `date_part('month', created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC` is immutable. Deriving UTC time (or the local time for any given time zone offset) always produces the same result, and the time zone is a given constant in this expression.

The name of the data type `timestamp with time zone` is a bit misleading, unfortunately. A given time zone is not stored at all. It just serves as input modifier to compute the corresponding UTC time, which is stored internally. (And as output decorator, adjusted to the `timezone` of the requesting client.) See:

- [Time zone storage in data type "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872761/time-zone-storage-in-data-type-timestamp-with-time-zone/28876266#28876266)

Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)
- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)